# Unable to import CSV table in a model on PostgreSQL

Tags: django, database, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am doing a project on Django with database connected to postgreSQL.

I did all the commands related to models as makemigrations and migrate so my tables appear on PgAdmin 4 correctly.

The problema is for a particular table "Dashboard_país" with 2 columns (id and nombre) I am not able to import csv table, when with the other models importing csv I didnt have any problem.

My model Dashboard_país looks like this:

class País(models.Model):
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)

```
class Meta:
    verbose_name = "País"
    verbose_name_plural = "Países"

def __str__(self):
    return self.nombre
```

I receive the next error when import my csv:

Running command:
--command " "\copy public."Dashboard_país" (id, nombre) FROM 'C:/Users/auxer/Desktop/pais.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER ENCODING 'UTF8';""
Start time: Thu Oct 19 2023 10:50:53 GMT+0200 (hora de verano de Europa central)
\copy: error de procesamiento al final de la l�nea

Processing error at the end of the line or something similar on english. I was searching on the internet and didnt find anyone with a similar error so I would be glad if anyone could help me

Thanks.

I tried import a simple CSV like this:

Id;Nombre
1;John
2;Emma
3;Michael

but it didnt work

I also tried using query tool but commands doesnt work.

Comment: 1) If it was laid out on one line like this `Id;Nombre 1;John 2;Emma 3;Michael` that would be an issue. Or is that just a copy/paste or editing issue? 2) Have you determined whether there are hidden characters at end of line? 2) Where is the CSV file coming from: OS and version, encoding, etc.

Comment: I solved the problem just making a query on PgAdmin and creating the rows manually. On the other hand, I dont really know exactly the issue but I think it was because some of the fields had ñ, accents or strange symbols that Postgress SQL didnt accept.

Comment: Postgres will accept many [character sets](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/multibyte.html#MULTIBYTE-CHARSET-SUPPORTED) and [convert character sets](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/multibyte.html#MULTIBYTE-CONVERSIONS-SUPPORTED). You just have to correctly indicate what the incoming encoding/character set is. Best guess, your CSV was not actually UTF8 but one of the Windows character sets.